# JBoss 7.1 JAX-WS webservice behind Reverse proxy, https to http transformation

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, jboss7.x, reverse-proxy, jboss-eap-6

I have deployed a JAX-WS web service hosted in a JBoss 7.1.1.
The webservice is acceded by a reverse proxy.
To access the service from the public internet, it has to be done by the http**s** protocol, but the communication between the reverse proxy and the JBoss is in http.
So the host present in the wsdl file is http 
`<soap:address location="http://example.com/WS"/>`
and it has to be
`<soap:address location="https://example.com/WS"/>`.

The JBoss configuration is as follows:

```
modify-wsdl-addres = true


wsdl-host = jbossws.undefined.host
```

Here is the reference for the webservices configuration:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Web+services+configuration

But I can find where to force the protocol to be https in the soap addres.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem and debugged a JBoss 7.1.1.
It turned out that it determines the URL at deployment time and looks at a "Transport Guarantee" configuration, which can be provided in various locations and formats.

I've annotated my Webservice like this:

```
@org.jboss.ws.api.annotation.WebContext(transportGuarantee="CONFIDENTIAL")
public class SomeServiceEndpoint implements SomeServiceInterface {
    ...
}
```

I'm using a Standard http Connector and configured the webservice subsystem like this

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
    <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
    <wsdl-host>proxy.com</wsdl-host>
    <wsdl-secure-port>443</wsdl-secure-port>
</subsystem>
```

Edit:
I've noticed that the http Connector needs to have the proxy-name and proxy-port attributes to accept the plain HTTP request made by the proxy.
The secure and scheme attributes are useful for Servlets etc., e.g. for creating URLs.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               socket-binding="http" executor="http"
               scheme="https" secure="true" 
               proxy-name="proxy.com" proxy-port="443"/>
    ...
</subsystem>
```

Comment: I can't test it now, but I not sure is I can make the host name fixed

Answer (score 1):

The `web` and `webservices` subsystem configurations work together to provide the endpoint URL (and also URLs for xs:import statements).

In the `webservices` configuration add the following line

```
<wsdl-port>443</wsdl-port>
```

In the `web` configuration change the scheme of the http connector from `http` to `https` and add `proxy-port="443"`

So it will look like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="http" 
     secure="true" proxy-port="443"/>
     ...
</subsystem>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
    <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
    <wsdl-host>jbossws.undefined.host</wsdl-host>
    <wsdl-port>443</wsdl-port>
    ...
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Make sens, but I don't have acces to the service to test it now. :(